# How do I apply for a USA transit visa for two entries (one out, one back)?

Tags: usa, transit-visas, chinese-citizens

I have a first layover in Los Angeles, USA on 20th Sep 2016 on my way to Europe and a second layover in Los Angeles on 29th Sep 2016. Basically two entries to the USA within ten days. But on my transit visa application form online, it only asks for date of arrival.

How do I deal with this situation?

Comment: What is your nationality?

Comment: Chinese with NZ residency

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The application only asks for your initial arrival date, not dates of every trip.  Transit visas like most other US visas have a period of validity and a specified number of entries.

The potential of getting a multiple entry C-1 or a limited number of entries (1, 2, etc) depends on your citizenship. There is a webpage that you can enter the country of citizenship and see what the limits are on entries, validity, etc.  But these are maximums not guarantees, as the consular staff can decide to limit your visa to less time or less visits.

https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/fees/reciprocity-by-country.html